# SFML - gluPerspective function not found

Tags: c

Out of all of the functions which aren't referenced, my gluPerspective returns an error when I try to use it. I know it has nothing to do with syntax or human error: I've been copy/pasting the line of code used by it right out of an SFML tutorial.

I'm using QT Creator.

Could someone tell me why this may be the case, and if so what I could do about it? Do I need to reference a library to my qmake file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
LIBS += -lglut -lGLU
```

Answer (score 4):

A function not being referenced sounds like a linker error. Have you linked to the glu library?

Comment: Yes, I'll actually post the answer to this question in a moment.